# Can't add remote for android studio

Tags: github

When I go to VCS->Import into Version Contrl->Share project on Github

then it pumps a error out

> 23:05:31 Can't add remote
>            fatal: remote origin already exists.
>            during executing git remote add origin https://github.com/TinaYun/My.git

I go to my Github website the My folder was created successful but nothing in it